# Sample Wiener process constrained to open (initial), high (max), low (min), close (final)

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, brownian-motion, wienerprocess, ohlc

With a Brownian bridge, one can sample a Wiener process constrained to a specified initial value and a final value.

Can the same be done when the process is constrained *also* to have a specified maximum and minimum value over the time interval?

One could select a very small subset of enough samples (simulations) that happen to have the desired minimum and maximum values (and final value). But is there a way to explicitly construct such samples?